# Multi document printing from document library?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Is there any one have solution for print multiple documents from Document library? User has option to select multiple documents or single document or inside folder.

I found commercial product "Unbounded Printing Services for SharePoint". But is so expensive. Please share me if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: We disabled client integration. Because our site enabled in FBA mode. In FBA mode explorer view will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Goto View>Explorer View

Then you can highlight multiple files, right click and print just like you would in Windows Explorer.

Comment: We disabled client integration. Because our site enabled in FBA mode. In FBA mode explorer view will not work.